# Increasing YouWave memory

Tags: android, memory, emulation, youwave-for-android

YouWave that is one of the emulators for runninng Android projects, needs more memory for running some applications.How we can increase YouWave emulator memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open file "youwave_vm01.xml" in "users/UserName/.Virtualbox/Machines/" and find the tag "Memory RAMSize="256" ..." in it and change the RAMSize.